# ¿Cómo configurar test case en katalon con datepicker?

Tags: javascript, script, datepicker, pruebas-unitarias

Tengo un problema con una prueba unitaria.
Uso Katalon y encuentra todos los campos MENOS los del datepicker... en ellos se cae y da error cuando selecciono una fecha:

```
09-08-2018 12:00:00 PM - [INFO]   - Finding web element with id: 'Object Repository/Page_Escritorio Acepta/a_1' located by 'By.xpath: id("ui-datepicker-div")/table[@class="ui-datepicker-calendar"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[@class=""]/a[@class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover"][count(. | //a[@href = '#' and (text() = '1' or . = '1')]) = count(//a[@href = '#' and (text() = '1' or . = '1')])]' in '30' second(s)
```

Luego da este error:

```
09-08-2018 12:00:38 PM - [FAILED] - Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Page_Escritorio Acepta/a_1' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Page_Escritorio Acepta/a_1' located by 'By.xpath: id("ui-datepicker-div")/table[@class="ui-datepicker-calendar"]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[@class=""]/a[@class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover"][count(. | //a[@href = '#' and (text() = '1' or . = '1')]) = count(//a[@href = '#' and (text() = '1' or . = '1')])]' not found)
```

Es decir no logra hacer click a la fecha (día seleccionado)

¿Alguien le ha pasado?

---

Este es un un script que hice de prueba para solo verificar el datepicker en otra web....

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys

WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/pruebasRamdon/Page_Datepicker  jQuery UI/span_Prev'))

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/pruebasRamdon/Page_Datepicker  jQuery UI/a_1'))

WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

Comment: Muestra un poco de tu código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hice este ejemplo:

WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/pruebaDatePicker/Page_Datepicker/i_Demo_fa fa-calendar'))

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/pruebaDatePicker/Page_Datepicker/li_12'))

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/pruebaDatePicker/Page_Datepicker/span_startDate'))

y se cae.... por ende no es mi web, en los datepicker no toma la fecha, no se por que ¿Qué me falta?

Comment: @VictorPerdomo listo, ya coloqué 2 codigos que estoy probando.. en ambos se cae cuando le doy al prev o next.... no los encuentra